# Cut points and critical points of the exponential map

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Suppose $ M $ is a complete Riemannian manifold with exponential map $ \exp : TM \rightarrow M $, and $ S \subseteq M $ is an embedded hypersurface with unit normal $ \nu $. The normal exponential map is defined by

$$ \epsilon: S \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow M \qquad \epsilon(x, t) = exp(x, t\nu(x)) $$

Let $ \delta : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ be the Riemannian distance function from $ S $ on $ M $:

$$\delta(y) = \inf\{d(y,x): x \in S\}$$

and define $ U = \{ (x, t) : (x, t) \in S \times \mathbb{R}, \; \delta(\epsilon(x,t)) = t \} $ and $ D = \{(x,t) : D\epsilon(x,t) \; \textrm{is injective}\} $.

It seems reasonable to conjecture that the inclusion $ D \subseteq U $ should hold true. Can anyone prove
or disprove this statement?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, when $M = \mathbf{S}^2$ and $S$ is an equatorial circle, then $U = S \times (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ whereas $D = S \times \{ \mathbf{R} \setminus \mathbf{Z} \cdot \pi/2 \} \cup S \times \{ 0 \}$.